# How to recreate unzip

Tags: sml

I'm trying to recreate unzip and this is what I've gotten so far, before hitting into a roadblock.

```
fun myUnZip [] = []
  | myUnZip ((x1,x2)::tail) = (* x1 :: myUnZip tail and also do x2 :: tail *)
```

Now, I know that second line is impossible, so that's why i put the comments there to show what I intend to do.
Any help on how I'm suppose to do this properly?

This is my second day at this language and I'm just trying to learn pattern matching. I'm currently reading the book Elementary Standard ML and it somewhat covers the topic of unzipping a tuple from a list. Although the book provided me with a solution, I was a bit overwhelmed by it and was hoping maybe someone else had a different solution towards it or could possibly provide some commentary on the book's unzipping solution.

Comment: What was the book's solution? After a few more days with the language, you'll find unzip becomes an obvious one/two-liner, so the example shouldn't be too hard to follow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
fun unzip [] = ([], [])
  | unzip ((x,y)::xys)  =
      let val (xs,ys) = unzip xys in (x::xs,y::ys) end;
```

Comment: Really neat solution, where did you see this?